# EXM Upgrade - Sitecore version 9.1.1 to 10.2

Tags: exm, upgrade

Our team is working on an upgrade from Sitecore version `9.1.1 to 10.2`. I am looking for specific guidance on what needs to be done to upgrade `EXM` hosted on a separate server. Is there any documentation on this topic? I'm not finding anything popping out in my searches.

Comment: Clarifying question:  EXM is enabled on the CM, and you have a separate Dedicated Dispatch Server configured.  Correct?  And you've performed the upgrade on CM, but unsure what to do with the DDS?

Comment: @PeteNavarra Correct on the separate Dispatch Server, but we have not yet started the upgrade process - still in planning

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore provides an [Upgrade Guide](https://sitecoredev.azureedge.net/%7E/media/93CC3A931DB7459AAC38BA111E0DD16D.ashx?date=20211207T101247) that has instructions for upgrading to `Version 10.2`.  Assuming that you are not upgrading from an `IaaS/PaaS/OnPrem` to `Container architecture`, the upgrade path is fairly straightforward.

That being said, the upgrade guide indicates that you'll be upgrading the `databases and xDB`, but that you'll also be installing NEW instances of each Sitecore instance.  This indicates to me that there's no straightforward just "upgrade" module for `Sitecore 10.2`, supported by the fact there's no upgrade zip provided on the Download's Page for 10.2

Looking at the table of contents for the Upgrade Guide provided, also suggests that new instances will be needed.
[image]

So to upgrade the separate `EXM Dedicated Dispatch Server`, should be as simple as installing a new instance of the `EXM Dedicated Dispatch Server`, redeploying your configurations, and disposing of the old instance.